# Cassandra schema table suggestions

Tags: cassandra

I need a suggestion on designing a Cassandra table schema.
I have a created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sams.events (
    addedtime timestamp,
    hostname text,
    appname text,
    eventtime timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (addedtime, hostname)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (hostname ASC)
```

Now these are my requirements:

1) I should be able to make range queries via addedtime, like from x date to y date

2) I should be able to query by appname and order the rows in ascending order using addedtime

How can I achieve this? I am ok to change the table schema.

Adding I have created Cassandra cluster of 2 DC and 3 nodes each.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you have only 2 apps. How many hostname you have, is it equal to or greater than number of nodes in the cluster ?  If yes, then you can try the following which can give you even spread of data.

```
CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.events (
appname text,
hostname text,
addedtime timeuuid,
eventtime timeuuid,
PRIMARY KEY ((appname, hostname), addedtime)
);

insert into events (appname, hostname , addedtime , eventtime ) values ('app1','host1',now(), now());
insert into events (appname, hostname , addedtime , eventtime ) values ('app1','host1',now(), now());
insert into events (appname, hostname , addedtime , eventtime ) values ('app1','host2',now(), now());
insert into events (appname, hostname , addedtime , eventtime ) values ('app1','host3',now(), now());
insert into events (appname, hostname , addedtime , eventtime ) values ('app1','host4',now(), now());
```

Query1: Range query by added time  (hoping your number of hostname is not a higher number, otherwise it will be big in clause)

```
select * from events where appname = 'app1' and hostname in ('host1','host2') and addedtime > maxTimeuuid('2015-08-23 00:46:00-0500') and addedtime < minTimeuuid('2015-08-23 00:49:19-0500') ;
```

Query 2: By App name (again hoping your number of hostname is not a higher number)

```
select appname,hostname,dateOf(addedtime) from events where appname = 'app1' and hostname in ('host1','host2');
```

NOTE: IN clause does not support ordering of data using a query.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need two tables to handle those queries.

To do a range query on addedtime, you'll need a table where addedtime is a clustering column rather than as a partition key as you show in your example.  That's because you can only do range queries on clustering columns.  So if you want to do the range query for each hostname, then you could have hostname as the partition key, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sams.events_by_hostname (
    addedtime timestamp,
    hostname text,
    appname text,
    eventtime timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (hostname, addedtime));

SELECT * FROM events_by_hostname WHERE hostname='host1' 
    AND addedtime >= '2015-08-22 14:00:39-0400' AND addedtime < '2015-08-22 14:00:41-0400';

 hostname | addedtime                | appname | eventtime
----------+--------------------------+---------+--------------------------
    host1 | 2015-08-22 14:00:39-0400 |    app1 | 2015-08-22 14:00:39-0400
```

To query by appname, you'll want a table with appname as the partition key and addedtime as the clustering column, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sams.events_by_appname (
    addedtime timestamp,
    hostname text,
    appname text,
    eventtime timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (appname, addedtime));

SELECT * from events_by_appname WHERE appname='app1';

 appname | addedtime                | eventtime                | hostname
---------+--------------------------+--------------------------+----------
    app1 | 2015-08-22 14:06:45-0400 | 2015-08-22 14:06:45-0400 |    host1
    app1 | 2015-08-22 14:09:33-0400 | 2015-08-22 14:09:33-0400 |    host1
```

To keep the two tables consistent, you can do your inserts using a batch, like this:

```
BEGIN BATCH 
    INSERT INTO events_by_hostname (hostname, addedtime, appname, eventtime )     
        VALUES ( 'host1', dateof(now()), 'app2', dateof(now()));
    INSERT INTO events_by_appname (hostname, addedtime, appname, eventtime ) 
        VALUES ( 'host1', dateof(now()), 'app2', dateof(now()));
APPLY BATCH;
```

In Cassandra 3.0, which will soon be in beta release, you'll be able to create the second table as a view of the first table.  Then when you modify the first table, Cassandra will update the second table automatically.

Comment: is it not fine to have addedtime as partition key and hostname as an indexed column?

Comment: Thanks Jim. I have created a cluster and my appname is limited to count of 2. Also I get a lot of events from a single appname. Making it as partition key makes all the records go into one Cassandra node which kind of clutter on node in a cluster and rest other cassandra nodes are lighter. Is there a way wherein I can query only by appname and my rows are spreaded accros nodes with a single appname

Comment: You can use a compound partition key to add cardinality, by combining one of your existing fields with appname, or create a new field for that purpose.  For example, you could add a date field to partition by appname and day, or appname and a random number from 1 to 3 to spread the data across three partitions, etc.